# Sort List Descending Based on a Field Value

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic4, angular8

I need to sort a value-based list of a field from a firebase collection. This field is called "rankeamento", its maximum value is 10 and minimum 0. The list must first introduce the item with the highest value and so on. 
(This list will be appended in the form of slides).

I researched on a pipe but still unsuccessfully

HTML =>

```
<ion-slides>
        <ion-slide *ngFor="let produto of produtos">
          <ion-card>
            <ion-card-header>
              <ion-card-title>{{ produto.nome }}</ion-card-title>
            </ion-card-header>

            <ion-card-content>
              <ion-avatar slot="start">
                <ion-img [src]="produto.caminho_imagem"></ion-img>
              </ion-avatar>
            </ion-card-content>

            <div class="ion-text-center ion-padding-bottom ion-padding-top">
              <ion-checkbox></ion-checkbox>
            </div>
          </ion-card>
        </ion-slide>
      </ion-slides>
```

---

TS =>

```
public produtos: any[] = [];

ngOnInit() {

    this._firestoreService.getCollection('produto')
      .pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll))
      .subscribe(produtos => {
        // FIELD PRODUTO.RANKEAMENTO \\
        this.produtos = produtos;
        this.loading = false;
      });

    this.modoUso.valueChanges
      .pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll))
      .subscribe(value => this.onChangeModoUso.emit(value));

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular no longer provides any pipes for sorting (such as the `orderBy` pipe). You may read up more about it over [here](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe).

However, you may choose to sort the list after returning the observables at the `subscribe()` block, by using JavaScript's [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

```
this._firestoreService.getCollection('produto')
  .pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll))
  .subscribe(produtos => {
    // FIELD PRODUTO.RANKEAMENTO \\
    this.produtos = produtos.sort((a, b) => b.rankeamento - a.rankeamento);
    this.loading = false;
  });
```